# OOM using PreparedStatement to executeQuery in loop

Tags: java, jdbc

I am using PreparedStatement executeQuery in a loop and got a OOM as below,

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRowFast(MysqlIO.java:2267)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:2044)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readSingleRowSet(MysqlIO.java:3549)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:489)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:3240)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:2411)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2834)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2838)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2082)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2212)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
```

Every query might query out about 100 records, when the loop came to the 7th or 8th, the error was out.

Code

```
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();

Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");

DataSource ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/ma30");

Connection conn = ds.getConnection();

PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

ResultSet res = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

Anyone has ideas?

Comment: Not without seeing your code.

Comment: The jdbc connection is generated from  tomcat context as below:

Comment: Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
        Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/ma30");
  Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
  PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
  ResultSet res = pstmt.executeQuery();

Comment: Edit your question, post the code there (you can lose the stacktrace, it's not important) and show the whole loop.

Comment: You are not closing the result set, statement and connection. This can lead to memory leaks as the connection pool might never reclaim them (or only much later).